# http.server: decoding POST request to JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, post, urldecode

i'm writing a very simple http-server based on `http.server` (using Python-3)

the client is supposed to send a json-object via POST.

```
payload={'text': 'bi ba buzemann!',
         'nouns': ['streetlight', 'situation'],
         'states': ['solid', 'fluid']
        }
requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

this arrives fine at the server, but in a serializd form

```
def do_POST(self:
  length = self.headers['content-length']
  data = self.rfile.read(int(length))
  # b'states=solid&states=fluid&nouns=oracle&text=bi+ba+buzemann%21'
```

now my question is: how do i turn this urlencoded result back into a dict (or the intermediate JSON)?

do i have to do this manually, as in:

```
for x in str(r).split('&'):
   y,z=x.split('=')
   if not y in d:
      d[y]=[]
   d[y]+=[urllib.parse.unquote_plus(z)]
```

or is there some well-debugged function available in some common module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change the request, then send it in JSON:

```
import json
payload={'text': 'bi ba buzemann!',
         'nouns': ['streetlight', 'situation'],
         'states': ['solid', 'fluid']
        }
requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `parse_qs` like so:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import parse_qs
>>> parse_qs(b'states=solid&states=fluid&nouns=oracle&text=bi+ba+buzemann%21')
{b'nouns': [b'oracle'], b'text': [b'bi ba buzemann!'], b'states': [b'solid', b'fluid']}
```

> Parse a query string given as a string argument (data of type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded). Data are returned as a dictionary.

So if your client is supposed to send in json, go with @BrentWashBurne's idea to post as json.